# Ubuntu 16.04 and [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] fan active most of the time

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, battery, amd-graphics

My notebook has Ubuntu 16.04 installed. But the fans are active most of the time. This reduces the time it can run on battery. This is unlike when I used Ubuntu 15.10.

When you run the command:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

I see these results:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)  
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] [1002:6841]
```

Does Ubuntu 16.04 work with this video card? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

See my recent post on configuring DPM:
https://askubuntu.com/a/825149/594936

Perhaps yours is not choosing the "Battery" profile (possibly due to the driver not having an exact devid match for your chipset, and it's mapping to a more generic bios, i.e. a desktop version of the chip).  The commands/tools referenced above should help you figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with kernel 4.4.0-22.40, but after updating to 4.4.0-24.43 it seems that the dynamic power management works properly:

```
    $sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
    0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
    1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

I got kernel 4.4.0-24.43 from the **xenial updates** repo.

P.S. The official version of an Ubuntu kernel is found in the `/proc/version_signature` file:

```
    $cat /proc/version_signature
    Ubuntu 4.4.0-24.43-generic 4.4.10
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and explain why you think this kernel should solve the issue and describe how to get it. The currently latest stable kernel available through the official Xenial repositories is **4.4.0.24.25**.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either downgrade to `14.04` or install open source AMDGPU/ATI drivers.

This is how I installed AMD drivers in my Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Download the AMDGPU-PRO from [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx)

Run the following commands in the terminal

`tar xvzf amdgpu-pro-16.40-XXXXXX.tar.xz`

`cd amdgpu-pro-16.40-XXXXXX`

`chmod +x amdgpu-pro-install`

`sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install`

Replace XXXXXX with the build number. Finally issue the following obvious command.

`sudo reboot`

To verify if it installed successfully issue `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro`

Source: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx