# How to see actual AMD GPU frequency with radeon driver on Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

How could I know the **actual running frequency** (not the vendor stock freq.) of my **AMD gpu** on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) ? 
I can't find any information about this.
I'm using the **radeon** driver.
On the good old days, *aticonfig* was giving bunch of useful informations... but AMD drivers doesn't exist anymore for Xenial : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

Answer (score 3):

For me (Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS, so I'm forced to the open source driver for my HD5670 1GB GDDR3 card) I found this useful (setting DPM must be run as root, or a user that has driver write permissions):

When I have DPM set to "balanced":

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/radeon_pm_info

uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 0    sclk: 20000 mclk: 40000 vddc: 900 vddci: 0
```

when I force it high (default is "auto"):

```
echo "high" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
```

I get:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/radeon_pm_info

uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 2    sclk: 77500 mclk: 66700 vddc: 1050 vddci: 0
```

If you prefer a GUI, there's a small project I came across, which also lets you create app launch profiles:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:trebelnik-stefina/radeon-profile
apt-get update
apt-get install radeon-profile
```

The installer failed due to a failed dependency on radeon-profile-daemon, but the tool still works.  I'm guessing this daemon has to do with older kernel versions that used a different approach for DPM.

Side note, I was playing with DPM because I noticed that while running 3D applications with Wine, my CPU cores and GPU were all very much under utilized, yet my FPS was randomly dipping down way low (i.e. 30-40 FPS) for no apparent reason.  Turning off DPM in the CPU and GPU (described above) got them up to a steady ~180-200 FPS.  I also needed to disable VSYNC lock in the driver, which I did by putting the following into a config file:

```
cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-radeon.conf

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Card0"
    Driver "radeon"
    Option "SwapbuffersWait" "off"
EndSection
```

Here's my CPU output after setting it to "Performance" using the `indicator-cpufreq` tool installed from Ubuntu Software Center:

```
grep -E "MHz" /proc/cpuinfo

cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
```

Comment: `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/radeon_pm_info` outputs `PX asic powered off`

Comment: ^ that is because my laptop has a hybrid graphics setup, so the dedicated AMD GPU was turned off. Launching something using `DRI_PRIME=1` will make the frequencies appear.

Answer (score 0):

You know the best way is to use AMDuProf.

To get AMDuProfDriver module working is a bit tricky. First uninstall the driver. Download the latest tarball from amd website (NOTE: *.deb package is most likely to not work).

**I Will not take credit here.**
SEE https://github.com/sibradzic/stapmlifier/
who is actual founder of the fix and patches. Download uprof.patch from there (or you may see instruction at the end of README)

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic build-essential libelf-dev
tar -zxf ~/Downloads/AMDuProf_Linux_x64_2.0.493.tar.gz
cd AMDuProf_Linux_x64_2.0.493/bin

MODULE_NAME=AMDPowerProfiler
MODULE_VERSION=$(cat AMDPowerProfilerVersion) # 7.02
mkdir $MODULE_NAME-$MODULE_VERSION
tar -zxf AMDPowerProfilerDriverSource.tar.gz
cd $MODULE_NAME-$MODULE_VERSION
```

If your kernel version is greater or equal to 4.18, then you need to patch it with patch provided uprof.patch

```
patch -p1 < ~/stapmlifier/uprof.patch
make

sudo mkdir -p /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/extra
sudo cp AMDPowerProfiler.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/extra/
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe AMDPowerProfiler
```

Create manual char node

```
VER=$(cat /proc/AMDPowerProfiler/device)
sudo mknod /dev/AMDPowerProfiler -m 666 c $VER 0
```